# Cinnamon stops working on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, desktop-environments, cinnamon, mir

I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 and cinnamon stops working. 
When I load cinnamon it only displays a slow responding cursor over a black screen. And the desktop never loads.

So (for getting access to my desktop) I purged cinnamon and did this :

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s unity
```

and when it didnt work I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/286349/126861)

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

And it restored unity.

Now When I install cinnamon it again runs into same old problem of - dark screen with only a cursor.
What do I do for getting cinnamon?